# Mongoid callback relationships not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

So I have an observer which looks like this:

```
class RecipeObserver < Mongoid::Observer

  def after_create(object)
    puts object.user
    puts "test"
  end

end
```

And so I have that working fine, but the relationship `object.user` is nil, like even though my Recipe class `belongs_to` a user, which `has_many` recipes as well. What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Update**

So here is my controller code and my model, if someone could please show me how a proper observer that creates another object works, that would be very helpful:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :new

  # ... other actions

  def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
    respond_with @recipe
  end

  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])
    @recipe.save

    respond_with @recipe, :notice => "You've created a recipe!"
  end
end
```

My models (truncated for brevity):

```
class Recipe
  include Mongoid::Document

  # ... other methods and such

  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name

  # ... other methods and such

  has_many :recipes
end
```

So the big problem is that calling `object.user` in the `after_create` method is nil, but it doesn't even throw an exception, just results in nothing being returned, which I find the most bizarre, I'm not sure really on how to start debugging this.

Comment: Can you paste how are you creating the recipe and assigning the User? 
Also check that the Recipe model doesn't attr_accessible/protected stuff.

Comment: hey @kain, thanks for your input, I've added some of my other logic n for you to take a peek at if you have time, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're actually assigning a user to the recipe anywhere. Try:

```
def create
  @recipe = current_user.recipes.build(params[:recipe])
  @recipe.save

  respond_with @recipe, :notice => "You've created a recipe!"
end
```